# What does "physical dimensions approaches the wavelength" mean exactly?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm learning Electronics by my own. And I'm in stuck while reading a book after failed to understand the following paragraph in Chapter 1, Electric Circuits 10th by Nilsson :

> On the other hand, the propagation frequency of radio signals is on the
>   order of 10^9 Hz.Thus the wavelength is 0.3 m. Using the rule of 1/10th, the
>   relevant dimensions of a communication system that sends or receives radio
>   signals must be less than 3 cm to qualify as a lumped-parameter system.
>   Whenever any of the pertinent physical dimensions of a system under study
>   approaches the wavelength of its signals, we must use electromagnetic field
>   theory to analyze that system. Throughout this book we study circuits
>   derived from lumped-parameter systems

It's about the definition about lumped-parameter circuit.

I have difficulty in understanding the sentence :

> Whenever any of the pertinent physical dimensions of a system under study
>   approaches the wavelength of its signals, we must use electromagnetic field
>   theory to analyze that system.

What does "physical dimensions approaches the wavelength" mean exactly?

What are the properties of physical dimensions?

And how do they approaches the wavelength?

---

It was just about the size and the length.

But.. I don't know why EM theory should be applied when the size approaches the wavelength. I might need to find that answer from EM theory.

Comment: physical dimension = size

Comment: *What are the properties of physical dimensions* - W x H x D. *And how do they approaches the wavelength* - getting close to either of the above.

Comment: they are talking about things like the length of antennas, or the size of waveguides, or size of holes in the door shield of a microwave oven .... etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the frequency is (say) 2GHz, then the wavelength is 150mm.

If the physical dimensions are big enough that they are said to "approach" (might be 7mm or 15mm) then you need to employ EM theory.

If the part is (say) an 0603 resistor you can treat it as a lumped element at those frequencies.

---

This use of "approach" is kind of a quirk in English. It just means that if you imagine the parts getting bigger and bigger at a given frequency so the sizes "approach" the wavelength then the parts no longer behave in such an ideal manner.

Answer (score 6):

The equation that relates wavelength and frequency for electromagnetic waves is:

λf=c

where λ is the wavelength, 
f is the frequency
and c is the speed of light in the dielectric ( is max. in  a vacuum ~ air )

[image]

Can see the generic term for "microwave band" covers from 1mm to 1m  ( sometimes called UHF)?

We generally say when the physical geometry approaches 10% of λ that lumped circuit no long applies and the reflections of waves such as 1/4 wave actually inverts impedance of the load back to the source since it opposes the polarity of the source wave.

An example was in the 80's we wanted to block the jamming signal on Cable TV Ch 23 so we computed the frequency and length of coax for a 1/4 wave and it became a high Q notch filter ~Q=100 just narrow enough to block the jamming signal on 75 Ohm coax but still pass the video, colour and audio.

Comment: @Tony, how did that work? Do you mean you added the coax length as a spur, so it would reflect the jamming signal and negatively interfere, cancelling it out?

Comment: Yes as a shunt connection on F connectors.  It was in the mid Band between 6 & 7  . Helicoil 1/4 wave stubs were even better with Q up to 1000